# Looking for a specific HTML tag using VBA

Tags: html, vba

I am attempting to navigate to a specific page on a website. The first time I open the page, it asks for a username and password, and every other time after that, it remembers me and is already logged in.
I know how to open a browser, how to navigate to specific page, and how to input the username and password to the correct places, all using VBA. I don't want to try and send a username and password when I am already logged in, because those tags wont even exist; the boxes to input those things aren't there. What I need to know is, is there a way to look for a *specific* tag to see if it is on the webpage in a VBA macro?

Edit: So, I've solved my problem by simply using "On Error Resume Next," so if it hits an error trying to input information to a element that doesn't exist, it'll just jump over it to the page navigation line. It may be a bit hacky, and I'll keep looking for a more elegant solution, but for now, it works. Thank you to all who replied!

Comment: can you post the HTML source for the tag?

Comment: If the element has an Id attribute then you can use `set el = doc.getElementById("theId")` assuming doc is a reference to the currently-loaded document.  el will be Nothing if the tag is not there.

Comment: This code is what works for submitting the user name and passowrd

`IE.document.Forms(0).all("Login").Value = "generic_login"
    IE.document.Forms(0).all("Password").Value = "generic_password"
    IE.document.Forms(0).submit`

So can i presume that "Login" and "Password" are the tag names? If not, any help you can give is greatly appreciated; I'm pretty new to anything HTML, and completely new to combining VBA and web pages.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the full HTML loaded in a string variable you can do something like this:

```
Dim HasLogin As Boolean, HTMLSource As String

HasLogin = (InStr(HTMLSource, "<input name=""login"" id=""username"">") > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Set up a loop for each input field in the HTML document and check the name like below.

```
Public Function isLoginScreen(IE As Object) As Boolean
  Set objCollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
  Dim i As Long, b As Boolean
  b=False
  i = 0
  While i < objCollection.Length
    If objCollection(i).Name = "Login" Or objCollection(i).Name = "Password" Then 
        ' You found your element
        b=True
        Exit Function
    End If
    i = i + 1
  Wend
End Function
```

You can see more here: http://www.excely.com/excel-vba/ie-automation.shtml